# Preserving spaces when scannig `tl` variables into a sequence using `\seq_set_split`

Tags: expl3

As stated in the interface3 document (Part IX, 1. Creating and initializing sequences) `\seq_set_split:` does not preserve spaces. Wishing to scan the text contained in a _tl variable into a sequence item by item for further processing (to be parsed for example) it would be advantageous to have spaces preserved. The MWE demonstrates that this can be achieved by introducing `hard spaces`, but is there a way to make do without the `~`s?

```
\documentclass{article}
% RN. 11 Nov 2018
%=======================
\usepackage[check-declarations,log-functions]{expl3}
\usepackage{xparse}
%-----------------------
\ExplSyntaxOn
\tl_new:N \l_rn_auxOne_tl
\seq_new:N \l_rn_auxOne_seq

\NewDocumentCommand\myScanText{m}
  {
    \tl_set:Nn \l_rn_auxOne_tl {#1}
    \textbf{tl~variable:}~\tl_use:N \l_rn_auxOne_tl\\
    \seq_set_split:NnV \l_rn_auxOne_seq {} \l_rn_auxOne_tl
        \textbf{seq~variable:}~\seq_use:Nn \l_rn_auxOne_seq {,}\\
  }  %  \myExperminent
\ExplSyntaxOff
%-----------------------
\begin{document}
  \verb+\myScanText{The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.}+\\  
  \myScanText{The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.}

  \verb+\myScanText{The~quick~brown~fox~jumps~over~the~lazy~dog.}+\\
  \myScanText{The~quick~brown~fox~jumps~over~the~lazy~dog.}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a slower routine first splitting at spaces.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=1cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\tl_new:N \l_rn_auxOne_tl
\tl_new:N \l_rn_auxTwo_tl
\seq_new:N \l_rn_auxOne_seq
\seq_new:N \l_rn_auxTwo_seq

\NewDocumentCommand\myScanText{m}
 {
  \tl_set:Nn \l_rn_auxOne_tl {#1}
  \seq_clear:N \l_rn_auxOne_seq
  % split at spaces
  \seq_set_split:Nnn \l_rn_auxTwo_seq {~} { #1 }
  % the first item is special, pop it out and split it
  \seq_pop_left:NN \l_rn_auxTwo_seq \l_rn_auxTwo_tl
  \tl_map_function:NN \l_rn_auxTwo_tl \__rn_add:n
  % now do the other items, reinserting the space before them
  \seq_map_inline:Nn \l_rn_auxTwo_seq
   {
    \__rn_add:n { ~ }
    \tl_map_function:nN { ##1 } \__rn_add:n
   }
  % print the data
  \textbf{tl~variable:}~\tl_use:N \l_rn_auxOne_tl\\
  \textbf{seq~variable:}~\seq_use:Nn \l_rn_auxOne_seq {,}
 }
\cs_new_protected:Nn \__rn_add:n
 {
  \seq_put_right:Nn \l_rn_auxOne_seq { #1 }
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff
%-----------------------
\begin{document}

\setlength{\parindent}{0pt} % just for the example

\myScanText{The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.}

\myScanText{The~quick~brown~fox~jumps~over~the~lazy~dog.}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Alternative method: first replace spaces with a private token and then split with `\tl_map_function:NN`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=1cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\tl_new:N \l_rn_auxOne_tl
\seq_new:N \l_rn_auxOne_seq

\NewDocumentCommand\myScanText{m}
 {
  \seq_clear:N \l_rn_auxOne_seq
  \tl_set:Nn \l_rn_auxOne_tl {#1}
  \tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_rn_auxOne_tl { ~ } { \__rn_space: }
  \tl_map_function:NN \l_rn_auxOne_tl \__rn_add:n
  % print the data
  \textbf{input:}~#1\\
  \textbf{seq~variable:}~\seq_use:Nn \l_rn_auxOne_seq {,}
 }
\cs_new_protected:Nn \__rn_add:n
 {
  \tl_if_eq:nnTF { #1 } { \__rn_space: }
   {
    \seq_put_right:Nn \l_rn_auxOne_seq { ~ }
   }
   {
    \seq_put_right:Nn \l_rn_auxOne_seq { #1 }
   }
 }
\cs_new_protected:Nn \__rn_space: {}
\ExplSyntaxOff
%-----------------------
\begin{document}

\setlength{\parindent}{0pt} % just for the example

\myScanText{The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.}

\myScanText{The~quick~brown~fox~jumps~over~the~lazy~dog.}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Why `\cs_new_protected:Nn \__rn_space: {}`?  This token should never be expanded anyway.

Comment: @HenriMenke Because it *should* have a definition.

Answer (score 4):

You could use `\str_map_inline:Nn` and append to the `seq`.  The problem is that catcodes are all 12 then.

```
\documentclass{article}
% RN. 11 Nov 2018
%=======================
\usepackage[check-declarations,log-functions]{expl3}
\usepackage{xparse}
%-----------------------
\ExplSyntaxOn
\tl_new:N \l_rn_auxOne_tl
\seq_new:N \l_rn_auxOne_seq

\NewDocumentCommand\myScanText{m}
  {
    \tl_set:Nn \l_rn_auxOne_tl {#1}
    \textbf{tl~variable:}~\tl_use:N \l_rn_auxOne_tl\\
    \seq_clear:N \l_rn_auxOne_seq
    \str_map_inline:Nn \l_rn_auxOne_tl { \seq_put_right:Nn \l_rn_auxOne_seq { ##1 } }
        \textbf{seq~variable:}~\seq_use:Nn \l_rn_auxOne_seq {,}\\
  }  %  \myExperminent
\ExplSyntaxOff
%-----------------------
\begin{document}
  \verb+\myScanText{The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.}+\\  
  \myScanText{The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.}

  \verb+\myScanText{The~quick~brown~fox~jumps~over~the~lazy~dog.}+\\
  \myScanText{The~quick~brown~fox~jumps~over~the~lazy~dog.}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You could pre-process the input using `\regex_replace_all:nnN` to replace all spaces with `\space`. (I first tried replacing spaces with `~` and `\~` but this did not work so well.) Doing this your MWE produces:

[image]

Here is the code:

```
\documentclass{article}
% RN. 11 Nov 2018
%=======================
\usepackage[check-declarations,log-functions]{expl3}
\usepackage{xparse}
%-----------------------
\ExplSyntaxOn
\tl_new:N \l_rn_auxOne_tl
\seq_new:N \l_rn_auxOne_seq

\NewDocumentCommand\myScanText{m}
  {
    \tl_set:Nn \l_rn_auxOne_tl {#1}
    \regex_replace_all:nnN {\s+} { \c{space} } \l_rn_auxOne_tl
    \textbf{tl~variable:}~\tl_use:N \l_rn_auxOne_tl\\
    \seq_set_split:NnV \l_rn_auxOne_seq {} \l_rn_auxOne_tl
        \textbf{seq~variable:}~\seq_use:Nn \l_rn_auxOne_seq {,}\\
  }  %  \myExperminent
\ExplSyntaxOff
%-----------------------
\begin{document}
  \verb+\myScanText{The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.}+\\
  \myScanText{The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.}

  \verb+\myScanText{The~quick~brown~fox~jumps~over~the~lazy~dog.}+\\
  \myScanText{The~quick~brown~fox~jumps~over~the~lazy~dog.}
\end{document}
```

Note that this replaces repeated spaces with a single `\space`, which I'm guessing is probably what you'd really want.